# Solutions to $x^x=1$?

Tags: calculus, limits

When $x>0$, how many solutions does $x^x=1$ have?

I found that $\lim_{x \to 0} x^x=1$. How does one show that this is the only possible answer?

Comment: How about $1^1$?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**hint**

for $x>0$,

$$x^x=e^{x\ln(x)}=e^0$$

Answer (score 3):

Take logarithms (to any base) to obtain $x\log x=0$ so for $x\gt 0$ (condition given in question - in particular $x\neq 0$) you need $\log x=0$ ie $x=1$.

Answer (score 2):

$$y=x^x$$
$$y=e^{x\ln x}$$
we know that $e^0=1$, so:
$$x\ln(x)=0$$
$$\ln(1)=0$$
so the solutions are $x=0,1$

although notice that at $x=0$ this is a limit and only exists for $0^+$

Answer (score 1):

By the hints above, we have
$$
x \ln(x) = 0.
$$
As $x >0$ we have $ \ln x =0$ which implies $x=1$ since the logarithmic function is a bijection.

As observed, we cannot have $x=0$ and the case $x<0$ is analogous.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x>0$ and $x^x=1$. Raise both sides to the power of $1/x$ to obtain
$$(x^x)^{1/x} = 1^{1/x}$$
which implies that $x=1$.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Graph for <span class=]$x^x$" />

Make the graph of the given function, and see where does the horizontal line $y=1$ cuts it.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is $x^{x}=1$. Now clearly $x=1$ satisfies the above equation because $1^{1}=1$. Again you can solve this above equation by taking $log$ on both sides.

$x^{x}=1$. Therefore $xln(x)=ln(1)$. Now substitute $x=e^{t}$. Therefore $te^{t}=1$. Now here I will introduce the concept of Lambert W Function. That is $W(xe^{x})=x$. Therefore now if I take Lambert W Function on both sides, then we will get $W(te^{t})=W(ln(1))$. Therefore you will get $t=W(ln(1))$. Therefore finally $ln(x)=W(ln(1))$. Therefore, $x=e^{W(ln(1))}$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Note that $x^x$ is not defined for $x=0$ therefore $x=0$ is not a solution.

Of course we have that for $x=1$ we have $1^1=1$.

To show that it is the unique solution let consider

$$f'(x)=x^x(\log x+1)$$

Comment: "Note that $x^x$ is not defined for $x=0$" That's a matter of taste. To me, $0^0=1$. It makes things like $e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$ work out nicely, and works in any combinatorial sense.

Comment: I assume that $0^0$ is not defined of course we can set $x^x=1$ for $x=0$ but then we can also set $x^x=1$ for $x=2018$ and it becomes a new solution. Am I right or am I missing something else? Thanks!

Comment: That's a strawman argument if I ever saw one. Anyways, I'm not trying to convince you. I've attempted that before without success. I'm here to inform any other readers of your answer that there are other conventions out there.

Comment: @Arthur Your observation are always interesting for me! I've a great opinion about your knowledge. But in that case, for the given context, I think that it is not correct assume $0^0=1$. Moreover note that the asker was assuming that $x=0$ is a solution not by your sophisticated and reasonable argument but since $\lim_{x\to 0}x^x=1$ and this is of course not correct as starement. Anyway your observation is very good and useful to me. Thanks again. Regards